# How can I put my Fortran routines (with their interfaces) in a DLL without using module?

Tags: dll, fortran

I have some Fortran routines which I want to export to a DLL file, these routines are overloaded (I use generic functions). Of course the definitions must be included in interface blocks which is easier using modules, say for example:

```
module myRoutines
! define the generic name
interface add
module procedure add_int, add_flt
end interface
contains
integer function add_int(i,j)
integer, intent(in) :: i, j
add_int = i + j
end function add_int

real function add_flt(a,b)
real, intent(in) :: a, b
add_flt = a + b
end function add_flt
end module myRoutines
```

**My question is** : how to export all this stuff to a dll file **without** using a module ?

I appreciate any help :).

Comment: You export it to DLL as any other set of Fortran routines. You must provide the intefaces by some other means though, perhaps by an include file.

Comment: is it possible to include the interfaces inside the DLL?

Comment: nope..................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to include generic interfaces or other kind of interfaces in a DLL or .so library. These require a Fortran specific format, like a module. Certain compilers can put the module information into the library (Cray), most produce a separate file (.mod), but a Fortran module must be present for both.

One can also use an include file. That is the approach that some C libraries that also supply Fortran interfaces do, e.g., FFTW in the `fftw.f03` file.